# Proof that there is no minimal dynamical system on $S^2$

Tags: dynamical-systems, spheres

Is there a proof that no continuous map $f:S^2\to S^2$ can be minimal (=each orbit is dense)? Where can I find it?

I know recent works characterizing the 2-manifolds admitting minimal maps, but I'm searching for a hopefully simple proof just for the case of $S^2$.

Comment: For each $f \in C(S^2,S^2)$ the function $f\circ f$ has a fixed point. Have a look in the comments here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253156/is-there-a-minimal-topologically-mixing-but-not-positively-expansive-dynamical

Comment: This is useful, but where I can find a proof?

Comment: This is a rather deep result. I know it from the book of Eisenack and Fenske: Fixpunkttheorie (1978), Kapitel 8. It is in german and as far as I know there is no english translation. The proof there relies on a FPT of Lefschetz. The comments on mathoverflow refers to the book of Dugundji and Granas: Fixed Point Theory (1980), Theorem 5.4, but I cannot find it there. However I think one should find it somewhere (explicit or implicit) in this book, too

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it in the book of Dugundji and Granas: Fixed Point Theory, the following way (here $d(f)$ denotes Brouwer's degree):

Proposition 5.2: If $f,g \in C(S^{n},S^{n})$ then $d(f\circ g)=d(f)d(g)$

Theorem 5.4: If $f \in C(S^{n},S^{n})$ and $d(f) \not= (-1)^{n+1}$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Thus if $f \in C(S^{2n},S^{2n})$, then $d(f\circ f) =d(f)^2 \not= -1=(-1)^{2n+1}$, so $f\circ f$ has a fixed point.